# Creating a new backend project in sails.js gives not found error in browser

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to create a new Sails.js project without front end with following command. Project creates but it shows not found in browser http://localhost:1337/ after `sails lift`. Why it doesn't work?

```
sails new project --no-frontend
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error. It's normal behaviour as you are creating backend without stuff to show something.